# Using the <select> tag from HTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, tags, html-select

I'm working on using the select tag to know which attribute to assign a value.

```
<select>
    <option value="selStr">STR</option>
    <option value="selDex">DEX</option>
    <option value="selInt">INT</option>
    <option value="selWis">WIS</option>
    <option value="selCon">CON</option>
    <option value="selCha">CHA</option>
</select>
```

How do I send the information to JavaScript to know which has been selected?

I've gotten it working with the help of Zero298, but thanks to everyone who is putting different ways to do this!

Comment: Usually you set the selected option directly with your server code when returning the select html.

Comment: Give it an `id`, use `var index = document.getElementById("whatever id").selectedIndex;`

Comment: Alright I've got it working. Thanks zero298

Answer (score 0):

Start by giving your select an Id

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="selStr">STR</option>
    <option value="selDex">DEX</option>
    <option value="selInt">INT</option>
    <option value="selWis">WIS</option>
    <option value="selCon">CON</option>
    <option value="selCha">CHA</option>
</select>
```

Then in your script do the following:

```
var e = document.getElementById("mySelect");
var selectedValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

selectedValue will be the string that is in the value attribute of the selected option.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select onchange="alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" >
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qxxdj/)